# How to add an object without it touching the source object?

Tags: scribblenauts-unlimited

I am using the object editor, and trying to make a character (specifically Isaac from BoI). The object I started with (the source object) was a Head. I am trying to add the legs onto the character now, but it won't let me because the legs are not attached to the head!

The farthest I can get them away is a little gap, by putting them on the head and then holding the button to move them down.

How do I get the legs to be a part of the character, but not have them touching the head??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the torso as the source object instead of the head. I've had problems with this too when playing and I sat the for a half hour figuring it out until I finally found the solution.